# Creating XSLT nodes dynamically/multiple XSLT nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I've been tasked with creating a form based on a government data form.  I managed to download the XSD schema file for the form, and am trying to build an XSLT template based on the schema.

Here's the deal: the schema includes a complex element that allows (maxOccurs) up to five instances.  Nested within it is another complex element that allows up to five occurrences.  And nested within *that* is yet another complex element that allows up to 100 elements.

5 x 5 x 100 = 2500 elements?  Ugh!!!

I'd really rather not write up to 2500 nodes in my XSL template (especially when they're the same nodes)!!!  Is there any way to write my template file such that either (1) it creates the nodes dynamically, or (2) it includes some kind of attribute (I don't know if one exists -- I haven't been able to find anything) that tells it, "okay, this might repeat up to X number of times"?

Thanks in advance . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessfully looking for a solution to this, I bit the bullet, did a copy/paste of all my elements, and just hardcoded them into the XSLT. :-(

Probably not the best solution, I know, but it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand the question, all you need is a template match that will apply to each occurrence of the particular node.

Basic example of this can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp).

If I don't understand the question, maybe you could provide clarifying detail.

Comment: Not a few minutes after posting this, I came across that same w3schools link (don't know how I missed it earlier).  I'm messing around with it to see what it does.

Comment: Well, I've been fighting with this thing, and haven't been able to get it to work.  Part of the problem with the W3Schools description is that it's entirely geared toward *reading* XML *into* XSLT and generating HTML.  I'm taking a web form (i.e. HTML), and am trying to *generate* XML output *from* XSLT.  Nowhere in these instructions do I see anything that describes how to do this.

Comment: Ray K: So you have HTML as a starting point? Is it more specifically  XHTML which should transform just like XML? There are some gotchas. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711842 for example and related questions.

Comment: Affirmative; it is an HTML form, not XHTML.  I posted a question that asks exactly that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920756/mapping-web-form-data-to-repeated-xml-elements  I will make it a point to check that link.

Comment: I was able to successfully set up my HTML XPath to get processed by the XSLT (see my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920756/mapping-web-form-data-to-repeated-xml-elements).  However, I still can't get it to process unless I explicitly write out the elements in the XSLT.  I am **not** about to write 2500 elements!!!

Comment: I just discovered why <xsl:for-each> won't work.  I ran a debug trace, and discovered that the code *first* pulls the XSLT template, then uses *that* template to prepopulate the fields in the XSL template.  So I need to find a way to predefine the XSLT before the form tries to save the data.  Ugh!!!