# Mapping web form data to repeated XML elements

Tags: xslt, webforms, xml-parsing, xsd, xml-serialization

I have gone all over the web looking for an answer to this, and have not been able to find one anywhere.

I'm trying to build a web form that uses `XSLT` to generate `XML` data.  I'm basing it on other forms that do the same thing, and have gotten small test structures to work fine.  However, I am running into all sorts of problems when I try to map it to repeated elements.

Here's a quick overview of what I have.  I have an `XSLT` file that looks similar to this (disclaimer: lines excluded for brevity; also, these are NOT the actual field names):

```
<someForm:Name></someForm:Name>
<someForm:Address></someForm:Address>
<someForm:Plan>
    <someForm:Step></someForm:Step>
    <someForm:Description></someForm:Description>
</someform:Plan>
```

I also have an associated schema that looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="Name" />
<xs:element name="Address" />
<xs:element name="Plan" maxOccurs="10">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Step" />
            <xs:element name="Description" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**Make note of the "maxOccurs='10'" in the Plan element!  This is where I'm having problems!**

I wrote a form (again, based on other, working forms) that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="getName" xpath="/*[local-name()='Name']">
<input type="text" id="getAddress" xpath="/*[local-name()='Address']">
<table>
    <tr><th>Step</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="getStep1" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan']/*[local-name()='Step']"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="getDesc1" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan']/*[local-name()='Description']"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works fine; I am able to submit data, and it creates the XML as I want.

**However, here is my problem:** I am trying to write my setup so it can accommodate up to ten rows (as per the maxOccurs setting).  It will NOT work when I try to do this:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="getStep1" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan']/*[local-name()='Step']"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="getDesc1" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan']/*[local-name()='Description']"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="getStep2" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan']/*[local-name()='Step']"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="getDesc2" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan']/*[local-name()='Description']"></td>
    </tr>
```

This gives me all sorts of problems, depending on how I tweak it.  Sometimes, it does not save any data (for Step and Description); sometimes, it saves the *same* data for both rows.

I have not been able to find *any* documentation that explains how this works.  I've tweaked the `XSLT`, `HTML`, and `schema`, all to no avail.  And this is frustrating the crap out of me.

Does anyone have any insight as to how to solve this?

Note: this is directly related to another question that I asked earlier: [Creating XSLT nodes dynamically/multiple XSLT nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713844/creating-xslt-nodes-dynamically-multiple-xslt-nodes)

Thanks in advance for any assistance . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I finally got this to work:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="getStep1" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan'][1]/*[local-name()='Step']"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="getDesc1" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan'][1]/*[local-name()='Description']"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="getStep2" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan'][2]/*[local-name()='Step']"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="getDesc2" xpath="/*[local-name()='Plan'][2]/*[local-name()='Description']"></td>
    </tr>
```

If you look at the xpath, notice the [1] and [2] after "Plan."  When I included those with the xpath, it worked with no problem.

Comment: You learn something everyday, I didn't realise position could be shortened to just the number.

Comment: Yeah, I came across an example somewhere (don't remember where) that used that syntax.  I tried it out, and lo and behold . . .

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which Plan element you want for each **tr**, i.e. the first **tr** needs to get the first Plan, and so on.
To do this you can use the position() function in your `[local-name()='Plan']` predicate, e.g.:

```
[local-name()='Plan' and position()=1]
```

for the first **tr**

```
[local-name()='Plan' and position()=2]
```

for the second **tr**, and so on.

This should get you started but you could probably also make your code smarter by looping to output **tr** elements.

The example XPath in your question would return **all** Step or Description elements as you are specifying a node-tree i.e. collection of nodes. The position function allows you to select a single node in the node-tree.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see what happens. Re: looping to output <tr>: that's actually exactly what I have in mind.  The maxOccurs is not 10; it's actually 100, and I'm not about to write that many elements.  However, I wanted to make sure that I could get this to work first before I programmed any loop to output the elements.